# value being passed by ajax is not recognized in the php script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, recursion

This is the ajaxhello.js function :aFunction which returns the gameweek value from ajax.php

```
    function aFunction(){
      var   gameweekVal = 1;/*This is a random value, which is used to make the db call during ONLOAD  */
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var PageToSendTo = "ajax.php?";
        var VariablePlaceholder = "gameweekVal=";
        var myVariable = gameweekVal;
        var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + myVariable;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               var dataReturn = xmlhttp.responseText;

           var ret=  document.getElementById("currentgameweek").innerHTML = dataReturn; 
           getFixtures(dataReturn); /*The dataReturn vale is passed to the getFixtures(aVal) This value should then be passed to ajax2.php and used to as a select value in the SQL statement. It's not working, why ? */
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

    function getFixtures(aVal){


       var  gameweekVal = aVal;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var PageToSendTo = "ajax2.php?";
        var VariablePlaceholder = "gameweekVal=";
        var myVariable = gameweekVal;
        var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + myVariable;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               var dataReturn = xmlhttp.responseText;

            document.getElementById("ajaxfixtures").innerHTML = dataReturn; 

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", UrlToSend, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

    /******************************************************/

        enter code here<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            include 'configuration.php';
            include 'connectTodb.php';
         /*   include 'dataformat.php'; */

            $sqli_query= " SELECT `gameweek` FROM `gameweeks` WHERE now() BETWEEN `start`AND `end`";


            $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sqli_query);

            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                print($row['gameweek']);
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>

    /****************************************************************/


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            include 'configuration.php';
            include 'connectTodb.php';
         /*   include 'dataformat.php'; */

            $sqli_query= " SELECT `gameweek` FROM `gameweeks` WHERE now() BETWEEN `start`AND `end`";


            $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sqli_query);

            while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                print($row['gameweek']);
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include 'configuration.php';
        include 'connectTodb.php';
        $gameweekValIn = $_REQUEST['gameweekVal'];/* The value is being passed when gameweekVal is enclosed in double quotes */

         print("<table  border='1'>");

      $sqli_query =   "SELECT `gameweek`,`home_team_id`,`home_team`, `away_team` FROM `fixtures` WHERE `gameweek`=".$gameweekValIn;
        $result= mysqli_query($connection,$sqli_query);

       print("<tr><th></th><th>$hash_symbol</th><th>$home_teamColHeading</th><th>$white_space</th><th>$white_space</th><th>$white_space</th><th>$away_teamColHeading</th><th>$white_space</th><th>$white_space</th><th>$white_space</th></tr>");

        while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

        print("<tr><td ".$row['gameweek']."></td><td>".$row['home_team_id']."</td>"."<td>".$row['home_team']."</td>"."<td>$Letter_P</td>"."<td>$Letter_S</td>"."<td>$Letter_H</td>"."<td>".$row['away_team']."</td>"."<td>$Letter_P</td>"."<td>$Letter_S</td>"."<td>$Letter_H</td>"."</tr>");  

        }

        print("</table>"); 

    mysqli_close($connection);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have included the ajaxhello.js, the first function aFunction() is used to get the gameweek value from  ajax.php,  this value is passed to the getFixtures(aVal) which should be able to use that as a selector in  ajax2.php

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: step 1:  open your browser's developer/network console  see/confirm what requests and responses are being sent/received.

Answer (score 0):

since you're using GET via Ajax. You url parameter should be something like this;

```
 Xmlhttp.open('GET', 'ajax2.php?variable='+answer+'&varible2='+answer2+',true);
 Xmlhttp.send();
```

For POST

```
 Xmlhttp.open('POST', 'ajax2.php', true);
 Xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 Xmlhttp.send('variable='+answer);
```

Hope this give a clear picture of what you may have gotten wrong

The in ur php you can get what has been parsed:

For GET

```
If(isset($_GET['variable'])){}
```

For POST

```
If(isset($_POST['variable'])){}
```